# FATAL: Received: 403 Forbidden when creating cache on Digital ocean with private gitlab runner

Tags: digital-ocean, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running tests on digital ocean servers using gitlab runner. I want to cache gems so it won't install gems from scratch for every build. The cache section in my `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
[runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    ServerAddress = "ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com"
    AccessKey = "KEY"
    SecretKey = "SECRET"
    BucketName = "cache-for-builds"
    Insecure = true
```

When the build finishes and runner tries to create the cache I see

[image]

I tried to regenerate Digital Ocean Spaces key and secret but it didn't help

[image]

Also I don't have any certs installed on my private gitlab runner bastion server

The cache space in the Digital Ocean UI looks like this:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?
How can I fix the Forbidden error?
How can I debug this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I was using outdated configuration format for cache section for gitlab runner version `11.5.1`. The correct configuration format is:

```
# /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
[[runners]]
 ...
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "cache_for_builds"
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com"
      AccessKey = "<key>"
      SecretKey = "<secret>"
      BucketName = "cache-for-builds"
      BucketLocation = "ams3"
```